# Using isKindOf in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, foundation

I use Xcode 8.0 beta to test my app, but after it convert my code 2.2 to 3.0, came out many unsolved bugs. Below the demo, Xcode8.0 appear the error message

> **1. Expected "{" after "if" condition...**

```
    if annotation.isKindof: (MKUserLocation) {
        return nil
    }
```

Second error is the map kit...I use iskind(of: MKUserLocation) still not work out, it will appear another error message

> **2.Braced block of statements is an unused closure**

```
    if annotation.isKindof: (MKUserLocation) {
        return nil
    }
```

> **3. Missing argument label 'of:' in call**

```
    if annotation.isKind(of: MKUserLocation) {
        return nil
    }
```

Comment: Saddly, it show another error message:  'isKindOfClass' has been renamed to 'isKind(of:)'

Answer (score 172, accepted):

The substitute for `isKindOf` in `Swift3` is:

```
if annotation is MKUserLocation {
    return nil
}
```

Comment: This solution always return true. So, not reliable

Comment: The solution only returns true if the condition is true :)

Comment: More like Python, I keep forgetting!